# "Returns true if changed" pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, return-type

The `Collection` interface in Java has, among others, these methods:

```
boolean add(E e)
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
boolean remove(Object o)
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)
boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

Common for these is what they return:

> true if this collection changed as a result of the call

Or in more general terms, returns true if the method call caused anything to change, false otherwise.

Does this pattern have a name? I would like to know more about it. I have not seen it  much elsewhere.

Comment: My _guess_ is that this is particularly useful in a multithreaded application.  If the collection changes, you might want to update a cache, fire an event, etc...  I seldom used the return value for that.  It is sometimes useful for unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a variation on the [operation result](https://medium.com/@cummingsi1993/the-operation-result-pattern-a-simple-guide-fe10ff959080) pattern; but rather shoddily implemented as it falls prey to [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

I call it a variation because the return value isn't indicating success, it's indicating *change*. Not changing something can be a successful outcome of an operation; these two are not inherently synonymous. `retainAll` is a good example here. If you end up retaining all the original elements; then you've encountered a success but no change.

Comment: Failure is indicated by an exception being raised.  Success is assumed.

Comment: @JimmyJames: The operation result pattern is often specifically used to _avoid_ what would otherwise be flow by exception when the failure is not an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: What would be a non-exceptional circumstance that would cause adding a element to an in-memory data structure e.g.: HashSet?

Comment: You could simply argue you don't need to signal *success*/*failure* in a template collection operation (because most, if not all,  of the failure cases can be statically detected at compile time).

Comment: One person's blog post doesn't make a pattern.  Even the author admits that it's not an "official" pattern, although their definition of "official" (that it appears in a book) is suspect anyway.

Comment: I used a similar pattern in situations where data was displayed on the screen: It returned an object describing what to change on the screen. Nil for no change. An object if that object needed to be redrawn. Something more complex when an object was added or removed (meaning entries in a table needed moving), and even more complex if the change meant a table entry changed its location, for example if the table was sorted by age, and the age of a person was corrected).

Answer (score 1):

I think calling this a 'pattern' is a stretch.  It's really just an approach to interface definition.  It's useful in sets, when you have extra steps when something new is encountered: instead of a call to check for membership and then adding to the set, you just call add and check the result.  For example, a simple cycle detection solution:

```
boolean cycleExists(Collection<Node> path) {
    Set<Node> traversed = new HashSet<>();

    for (Node n : path) {
        if (!traversed.add(n)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

A similar approach is used with Map.put() but instead of returning a boolean, if you update an existing key, it returns the value that was associated with the key prior to the call.

You'll see this used in a lot of the concurrent APIs.  For example [compareAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-) in AtomicInteger.  In that secenario, it's more of a necessity due to the atomic nature of the call.